# API WOOCOMERCE (INSERT PRODUCT) - Whitespace on attributes (options)

Tags: api, rest, woocommerce

I have the following problem.

I'm uploading a product via api rest v3.

I have the problem loading a**ttribute options**

**If I use a space option, it separates the terms.**

If Gravina Di Catania loads, Gravina takes me then Di and then Catania

If I do the test on postman everything is ok

If I make the call via Php no.

how do i fix it?

I put double quotes in the string.

I used addslashes

i tried doing JSON ENCODE of options array